# Problems unraring a split file in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: decompression

I installed rar but when i run unrar x -e file_name.part01.rar I get the error message "Failed".

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong.

I'm pretty new to ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to open a split archive file, and you don't have all the parts of the file in your present working directory, you're going to get an error message saying that parts of the archive are missing. However if you just want to extract the first part(s) of the split archive, you can do it using the Archive Manager application which is installed by default in Ubuntu.

The files in a split archive that has missing parts will be extracted by default to a hidden folder, so you will have to use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to view the hidden folder.

You can't extract the files from part of a split archive unless you have all of the previous parts of the archive.